# C++ one thread for server and another one for optimization

Tags: c++, multithreading, rest

I want do develop an application in C++ that has one thread for a server and another for the optimization program which I am currently developing.

The server thread must listen for POSTs on the network and must be able to pass the received data to the optimization module.

The optimization program must run continuously and independently from the server thread and at the end of each iteration it must check if there is data on the server thread's side.

Currently I'm using cURL to GET data from a REST API but I need a more robust mechanism to be able to accept POSTs.

Can you give me guidelines about how to do it or where to look? Can you recommend any library to facilitate the development process?

**[Update to clarify my post]**
what tools or library to use to implement the HTTP server in the network communications thread?

Comment: I'm confused, are these two threads or two separate programs?

Comment: can't you just use a pipe or a shared memory object?

Comment: Same program two threads. One will be responsible for communication and another one for optimization.

Comment: What research have you done yourself?

Comment: So the server thread gets data using curl, and passes it to the optimisation thread?

Comment: C++11 and later have all you need to write your programme. Since you only have 2 threads, communication using a container (list, vector, etc) and a mutex should be easy.

Comment: @didierc at the moment my program is single thread: I just GET the data and then start the optimization process and after each iteration of optimization I do another GET to check is there are any updates.

Comment: @didierc The question is not how to perform the inter-thread communication, but on what tools to use to implement the HTTP server in the network communications thread. Is cURL adequate/recommended?

Comment: I'm sorry but asking for library recommendation is offtopic.

Comment: @didierc Err, so you're telling me that asking for how to solve a programming problem is off-topic on SO?

Comment: @EmanuelEy No, I'm telling OP that certain categories of questions pertaining to solving programming problems are off topic. please check out the FAQ, the different reasons for closing questions, and you'll get an idea of which topics are accepted on stack overflow.